# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, mysql-python

I am learning to implement Flask application.
And using mysql as a database.
I tried MySQLdb, flask_mysql & flask_sqlalchemy.

But still getting this error, when i try to perform any action on database :

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2059, "Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded: The specified module could not be found.\r\n")

I also tried :
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password  BY 'root';

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: now getting 1193, "Unknown system variable 'tx_isolation'" error

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to install the mysql client. On Debian based systems you can use `sudo apt install mysql-client -y`. I ran into this while using the Python 3.6 Docker image.